# error: Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)

Tags: android, xml

I am working on an application, in which i have a following xml. but when i try to clean/build my project the following error occurs:

"error: Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">
```

What does it possibly mean ? Thanks for help. :-)

Comment: why do you have the manifest tag in your layout xml?

Comment: You need that tag in manifest file not in your layout xml file

Comment: Please I need the right tab :(

Comment: what is that your doing its unclear what you have posted is it an layout xml or a manifest.xml?

Comment: layout.xml but now another problem: [2013-09-30 03:50:16 - MeuAplicativo] Installation error: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED [2013-09-30 03:50:16 - MeuAplicativo] Please check logcat output for more details. [2013-09-30 03:50:16 - MeuAplicativo] Launch canceled!

Comment: post your manifest and the layout xml and check the links in my post

Comment: package Meu.Aplicativo;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.AlertDialog;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import com.exemplo.meuaplicativo.R;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ...

Comment: would pls edit your question and post the same there not in comment section that is not manifest file that is an activity class

Answer (score 0):

Use this for your layout xml file

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">
 // other widgets
</RelativeLayout>
```

For manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="your package name"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="12"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="packagename.activityname"
             >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
       // make entry for other activities
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Also check the docs

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html

And for manifest file

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html

Answer (score -1):

Hi There try this i think it will works.

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I did it, now another problem:

   [2013-09-30 03:50:16 - MeuAplicativo] Installation error: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED
[2013-09-30 03:50:16 - MeuAplicativo] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2013-09-30 03:50:16 - MeuAplicativo] Launch canceled!

Comment: have u added any libraries to ur project have mentioned those in manifest file

Comment: Better wipe ur emulator and try to run the application

Comment: first close ur emulator and open the avd manager and select the emulator and check wipe device and click start then only it will wipe